# What is the difference of this private Textview and without private code?

Tags: java, android, firebase

### is there any difference if use

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private Textview xxxx;

@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


xxxx = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
```

or like this

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

Textview xxxx;

@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


xxxx = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
```

what is the difference if use **private** in front of TextView

Comment: Right it is accessible from any class by creating object means we can change its behavior anytime in any place but as per coding guidelines we should restrict our resources as per the need as you will only use this object in this class only so mark it as Private.

Comment: got the idea. thank you